# Drawing vertical and horizontal lines at each point x,y point using python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

As the title states I have some random X and Y data points:

```
+-----+-----+
| P1X | P1Y |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |   2 |
|   2 |   3 |
|  -1 |   4 |
+-----+-----+

d = {'P1X': [1,2,-1], 'P1Y': [2,3,4]}
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and then I graph them using a scatterplot like so:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_data, x='P1X', y='P1Y', legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now how would I draw a black line horizontally and vertically at each point?
Any and all answers are apprecatied!

Comment: Lines that fully spans the axis? so you'd have 3 vertical lines at -1, 1, 2, and 3 horizontal lines at 4, 3, 2, or just like smaller cross-hairs?

Comment: What about axvline and axhline? I think that's what you're looking for. Both need the respective y-x value, and the min/max value. Both of these values you can calculate based on the data you have.

Comment: @ALollz Yes, that's what I'd want. Idk if seaborn is the right thing for it, but this is my starting point. I am not too good at graphing stuff lol

Comment: @Sandertjuhh I plan on setting limits to the xlim and ylim for my actual data, would I just use that for the min and max?

Comment: @Sandertjuhh So I was looking into axvline and axhline. It doesn't look like it takes a pandas series. Would I just have to loop through my df and call that for each pairs of points? or is there a better way than a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop over the x and y values, and call axvline and axyline from plt.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_data = [-1, 2, 3]
y_data = [2, 3, 5]

plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, c='red')

for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data):
    plt.axvline(x=x, color='b', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=y, color='g', linestyle='-')
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, after your suggestion I was looking into it. I wasn't sure if there was a better way than just looping through my df and doing that, or if I could pass an a series for it. Thank you!

Comment: @mike_gundy123 I guess it doesn't get much easier than this. Please accept this as answer if it is what you're looking for :).

Answer (score 2):

Since you plan to manually set the limits of the plot then you can use `ax.hlines`/`ax.vlines`, sending arrays of the unique point coordinates for each.

```
xlims=(-1.1, 2.1)
ylims=(1.9, 4.9)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df_data.plot(kind='scatter', x='P1X', y='P1Y', ax=ax)

ax.hlines(df_data['P1Y'].unique(), xlims[0], xlims[1], color='grey', zorder=-1)
ax.vlines(df_data['P1X'].unique(), ylims[0], ylims[1], color='grey', zorder=-1)

ax.set_xlim(xlims)
ax.set_ylim(ylims)
```

[image]